# Duda sobre sockets

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

soy nuevo usando sockets con react y me ha surgido esta duda

```
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("User connected!");
    // socket.off();
});
```

Al momento de ejecutar este evento desde el lado del frontend el navegador me manda **dos veces el user connected**. ¿No debería mandármelo una sola vez?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como tengo configurado el servidor:

```js
const express = require ("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const io = socketIo(server,{
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})

io.on("connection", (client) => {
    console.log("User connected!");
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("User disconnected!");
    })
    client.on("sendMessage", (msg) => {
        io.emit("sendMessage", msg)
    })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("RUNNING", port);
})
```

Y así está el código del frontend:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socket from "./config/socket";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";

const App = () => {

    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("User connected!");
        // socket.off();
    });

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Chat</h1>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default App;
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas debuggin usando el evento `close` (algo como `socket.on("close"...`) para descubrir que está cerrando la conexión.

Comment: Me pasa algo parecido pero con Angular en ionic, vamos a ver si se debe a algun bug o algo en especifico, por ej una configuracion de parte de socket, etc. No deberia ejecutarse el evento de conexion varias veces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te suecede esto porque esta pasando dos veces por donde capturas el evento, el "socket.on" y esto hace que se quede escuchando dos veces el evento.

Para asegurarte que solo pasa una vez, puedes utilizar un useEffect:

```
useEffect(() =>{
 socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("User connected!");
    });
},[])
```

Comment: Entiendo el uso de useEffect para correr solo una vez y tener una captura, pero me quedan dudas con el socket ¿A que te refieres con que pasa 2 veces? Saludos

Comment: Poniendo el "socket.on" donde lo ha puesto sin un useffect, cada vez que ese componente tenga que renderizar por lo que sea, va a capturar el evento y se va a quedar escuchando, es decir cada vez que se renderiza se van acumulando las veces que escucha el evento "connect", he dicho dos, porque su ejemplo en la consola, sale 2 veces, pero podrían ser mas, en función de cuantas veces renderiza el componente